# Logic Pro X and SymLinked Files

Tags: finder, symlink, logic

I use Logic Pro X, and it's very particular of the naming of the directories it uses.

I'm SymLinking the Gigabytes of extra content it's downloaded from external drives. HOWEVER I wanted to ask something about the naming of the directories.

I want to name the original directories located on the external as **"folderName[Sym]"** so I can remember that it's being SymLinked. And then the actual SymLink on the main drive will just be **"folderName"**.

Will Logic *(or any program requiring default directories)* see just the name of the SymLink file and be ok? Or will it follow the path, see the actual file is names **"folderName[Sym]"** and tell me I've done something wrong?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, but you can rename symlinks and aliases without renaming the original file.

Comment: Ok, so if Logic is looking for a required directory named "Apple Loops", and I name the relocated file "Apple Loops [Sym]", will Logic still respond correctly if the SymLink of "Apple Loops [Sym]" is named "Apple Loops"?

Comment: If you have the folder "/Volumes/ExtHD/Apple Loops (SymLinked)" linked to "/Library/AppSupport/Logic/Apple Loops", then yes, it should work.